# How can I read a tab delimited file into a multidimensional array using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, csv

For the following tab delimited file, I'm trying to save it in `double[][] csvArray`

The number of cols are final (5), but rows is dynamic

```
1,717.72    1,728.89    1,712.61    1,728.89    1,707.11
1,701.19    1,704.11    1,702.05    1,706.98    1,697.19
1,685.41    1,688.68    1,694.07    1,695.71    1,687.20
1,641.05    1,649.27    1,658.06    1,658.58    1,648.09
1,673.69    1,668.34    1,663.90    1,673.42    1,662.16
1,682.32    1,669.54    1,671.33    1,681.02    1,668.81
1,688.12    1,681.44    1,684.90    1,688.57    1,672.60
1,686.02    1,690.76    1,697.13    1,698.13    1,690.35
1,704.92    1,696.22    1,696.74    1,701.17    1,688.74
1,686.78    1,683.61    1,677.03    1,687.88    1,674.40
1,705.94    1,704.90    1,715.58    1,716.91    1,700.25
1,659.22    1,660.46    1,658.69    1,664.98    1,655.62
1,622.31    1,621.94    1,632.78    1,633.61    1,613.91
```

Is there some LINQ expression that can get this nice and clean besides of iteration the whole matrix?

Answer (score 3):

With the help of *Linq* you can do it like this:

```
using System.Globalization;

var csvArray = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\MyData.csv") // assuming that data is in the file
  .Select(line => line
    .Split('\t')
    .Select(item => Double.Parse(item, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    .ToArray()) 
  .ToArray();
```

note, that when using *jagged* arrays (`double[][]`) you have no need to know exact number of columns (5 in your case)

Comment: I was wondering if you could say something about the efficiency of using this LINQ vs matrix iteration. I'm new to LINQ myself. Two calls to `ToArray()` makes me think if I am overdoing something.

Comment: That code is *quite efficient*: file reading (which you can't avoid) is the most cosuming part of it.

Comment: are you sure it is compiling? I am getting 'does not contain a definition for 'InvariantCulrure''

Comment: add `using System.Globalization;` to outher `using`s

Comment: Getting this as `double[][]` will result in all data loaded in memory. Consider using `IEnumerable` (removing the `.ToArray()` calls)

Comment: @Ahmed Al Hafoudh: the question states that `csvArray` should be `double[][]`. You're right: if it's possible not to *materialize* (i.e. skip the last `ToArrray()`) is should not be done.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to work.

```
string str = 
  @"1,717.72    1,728.89    1,712.61    1,728.89    1,707.11    
    1,717.72    1,728.89    1,712.61    1,728.89    1,707.11";

var doubles = str
  .Split("\n\r".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Select(item => item
    .Split("\t".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(d => double.Parse(d))
    .ToArray())
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: eh, `item.Split("    "...` seems to be incorrect and `items.Split('\t')...` will do (the question states that *tabulation* is used as a deriver)

Comment: fixed.. Now , will throw exception as "       " are not really tabs above lines